# Problem to obtain value of BLE Characteristic ESP32

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I hope can help me with this issue that I have on my project, Im new working with Bluetooth communication and BLE mode on ESP32, so I grateful your comprehension if I do basic mistakes

I have 2 esp32, one setup like ble notify mode and the other like client, the esp32 on notify mode, read 2 ADC and 1 digital input and advertise them on 3 characteristic with different UUID, This code runs apparently good because when I used the nrf connect app, It detect the esp32 ble, I can connect with it and see the service, the 3 characteristics and your value of each characteristic. The issue is when I run the client code on my other esp32 because it can obtain the 2 ADC reads(ejex and ejey), but the digital input(boton) reads is wrong, in fact, I obtain the correct value for digital input but it overwrite with the value of the last ADC reading (ejeychar)

[1)Client reading proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4DVj.png) 
[2)Client reading proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMPXw.png)

The next is my esp32 notify code

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
 #include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h> //descriptor para la configuración del cliente que tiene un UUID de 0X2902
const int pinJoyX = 32;
const int pinJoyY = 35;
const int pinJoyButton =33;
int ejex=0;
int ejey=0;
int boton=0;

//Nombre del servidor BLE
#define bleservername "control RBKT"

//Variables de tiempo
unsigned long lastime=0;
unsigned long timerdelay=50;

bool deviceconnected=false;
#define service_uuid "91bad492-b950-4226-aa2b-4ede9fa42f59"
BLECharacteristic ejeXCharacteristics("cba1d466-344c-4be3-ab3f-189f80dd7518", BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLEDescriptor ejeXDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902));
BLECharacteristic ejeYCharacteristics("f78ebbff-c8b7-4107-93de-889a6a06d408", BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLEDescriptor ejeYDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));
BLECharacteristic SWCharacteristics("ca73b3ba-39f6-4ab3-91ae-186dc9577d99", BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLEDescriptor SWDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2903)); //0x2903

//Setup callbacks onConnect and onDisconnect
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks 
{
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) 
  {
    deviceconnected = true;
  };
  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) 
  {
    deviceconnected = false;
  }
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(pinJoyButton ,INPUT_PULLUP);
  //Crea dispositivo BLE
  BLEDevice::init(bleservername);
  
  //Crea servidor BLE
  BLEServer *pServer=BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks);
  
  //Crea el servicio BLE
  BLEService *axisservice=pServer->createService(service_uuid);
  
  //Crea caracteristica y descriptor BLE de los ejes
  axisservice->addCharacteristic(&ejeXCharacteristics);
  ejeXDescriptor.setValue("Posicion Eje X");
  ejeXCharacteristics.addDescriptor(new BLE2902());//&ejeXDescriptor
  
  axisservice->addCharacteristic(&ejeYCharacteristics);
  ejeYDescriptor.setValue("Posicion Eje Y");
  ejeYCharacteristics.addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  axisservice->addCharacteristic(&SWCharacteristics);
  SWDescriptor.setValue("BOTON");
  SWCharacteristics.addDescriptor(new BLE2902());//new BLE2902()
  
  // inicamos el servicio
  axisservice->start();

  //iniciamos a publicar
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising=BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(service_uuid);
  pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
  Serial.println("Esperando conexion de cliente para notificar");
}

void loop()
{
  if(deviceconnected)
  {
   if((millis()-lastime)>timerdelay)
   { 
    ejex=analogRead(pinJoyX);
    delay(50);                 //es necesaria una pequeña pausa entre lecturas analógicas
    ejey=analogRead(pinJoyY);
    boton=digitalRead(pinJoyButton);
    Serial.print("Eje X:");
    Serial.println(ejex);
    Serial.print("Eje Y:");
    Serial.println(ejey);
    Serial.print("SW:");
    Serial.println(boton);
    static char EJEX[4];
    dtostrf(ejex,4,0,EJEX);
    ejeXCharacteristics.setValue(EJEX);
    ejeXCharacteristics.notify();

    static char EJEY[4];
    dtostrf(ejey,4,0,EJEY);
    ejeYCharacteristics.setValue(EJEY);
    ejeYCharacteristics.notify();

    static char SW[1];
    dtostrf(boton,1,0,SW);
    SWCharacteristics.setValue(SW);
    SWCharacteristics.notify();
    
    lastime=millis();
   }
  }
}
```

And this is my esp32 client

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
// nombre del otro esp32 en modo servidor
#define bleservername "control RBKT"
//UUID del servicio que buscaremos
static BLEUUID carserviceUUID("91bad492-b950-4226-aa2b-4ede9fa42f59");

static BLEUUID ejeXUUID("cba1d466-344c-4be3-ab3f-189f80dd7518");
static BLEUUID ejeYUUID("f78ebbff-c8b7-4107-93de-889a6a06d408");
static BLEUUID SWUUID("ca73b3ba-39f6-4ab3-91ae-186dc9577d99");

static boolean doConnect=false;
static boolean connected=false;

static BLEAddress *pserveraddress;
//caracteristicas que queremos leer
static BLERemoteCharacteristic* ejeXCharacteristics;
static BLERemoteCharacteristic* ejeYCharacteristics;
static BLERemoteCharacteristic* SWCharacteristics;

//Activar notificacion
const uint8_t notificationOn[] = {0x1, 0x0};
const uint8_t notificationOff[] = {0x0, 0x0};

//variables para almacenar valores del joystick
char* ejexchar;
char* ejeychar;
char* swchar;
int ejex=0;
int ejey=0;
int swbt=0;

//banderas si hay nueva lectura disponible
boolean newejex=false;
boolean newejey=false;
boolean newsw=false;

//Connect to the BLE Server that has the name, Service, and Characteristics
bool connectToServer(BLEAddress pAddress) 
{
   BLEClient* pClient = BLEDevice::createClient();
 
  // Connect to the remove BLE Server.
  pClient->connect(pAddress);
  Serial.println(" - Conectando al servidor");
 
  // Obtain a reference to the service we are after in the remote BLE server.
  BLERemoteService* pRemoteService = pClient->getService(carserviceUUID);
  if (pRemoteService == nullptr) 
  {
    Serial.print("Error en encontrar el servicio ");
    Serial.println(carserviceUUID.toString().c_str());
    return (false);
  }
   
  ejeXCharacteristics=pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(ejeXUUID);
  ejeYCharacteristics=pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(ejeYUUID);
  SWCharacteristics=pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(SWUUID);
  if(ejeXCharacteristics==nullptr || ejeYCharacteristics==nullptr || SWCharacteristics==nullptr)
  {  
    Serial.println("Error en encontrar la caracteristica");
  }
  Serial.println("Caracteristicas encontradas");
  //Asignacion de llamados para las caracteristicas
  ejeXCharacteristics->registerForNotify(axisXNotifyCallback);
  ejeYCharacteristics->registerForNotify(axisYNotifyCallback);
  SWCharacteristics->registerForNotify(SWNotifyCallback);
  return true;
}

class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks
{
  void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice)
  {
    if (advertisedDevice.getName() == bleservername)  //checa si los nombres coinciden
    {
      advertisedDevice.getScan()->stop(); //Scan can be stopped, we found what we are looking for
      pserveraddress = new BLEAddress(advertisedDevice.getAddress()); //Address of advertiser is the one we need
      doConnect = true; //Set indicator, stating that we are ready to connect
      Serial.println("Dispositivo encontrado, conectando...");
    }
  }
};

static void axisXNotifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify) 
{
  //store temperature value
  ejexchar=(char*)pData;
  ejex=atoi(ejexchar);
  newejex=true;
}

static void axisYNotifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify) 
{
  //store temperature value
  ejeychar=(char*)pData;
  ejey=atoi(ejeychar);
  newejey=true;
}
static void SWNotifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify) 
{
  //store temperature value
  swchar=(char*)pData;
  //swbt=atoi(swchar);
  newsw=true;
}

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("Iniciando sistema v0.1...");
 //Se inicializa dispositivo BLE
 BLEDevice::init("");
 // Retrieve a Scanner and set the callback we want to use to be informed when we
 // have detected a new device.  Specify that we want active scanning and start the
 // scan to run for 30 seconds.
 BLEScan* pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan();
 pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
 pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true);
 pBLEScan->start(30);
}

void loop()
{
 if(doConnect==true)
 {
  if(connectToServer(*pserveraddress))
  {
   ejeXCharacteristics->getDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902))->writeValue((uint8_t*)notificationOn, 2, true);
   ejeYCharacteristics->getDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902))->writeValue((uint8_t*)notificationOn, 2, true);
   SWCharacteristics->getDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902))->writeValue((uint8_t*)notificationOn, 2, true);
   connected=true;
   Serial.print("si esta conectado");
  }
  else
  {
   Serial.println("Error al conectarse al servidor");
  }
  doConnect=false;
 }
  Serial.print("EJE X:");
  Serial.println(ejex);
  Serial.print("EJE Y:");
  Serial.println(ejey);
  Serial.print("Boton:");
  Serial.println(swchar);
  delay(2000);
}
```

The code reference where I based my code is the tutorial of [Randomnnerdtutorials esp32 ble server client](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ble-server-client/)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

So in general your code design is very bad, the way you are sending payloads are very unefficient, 3 notifications services aren't justified in your use case.
But if this gets your work done even not in best way then its okayish i guess.

I didn't ran your codes since i dont have two esp32 with me, and the issue which i think is race conditions on having to receive multiple notification values at once. Altough i should also state that the ble stack ideally support multiple notifications at once.

Why i think that its race is cuz you yourself said nrfConnect recives the data just fine, but in esp32 you are subscribing to 3 notifications
at client side as well as sending them at server side, practically at once.

According to me any of the below three things can be done to hopefully resolve your issue:-

1. Notify each service one by one- once you recive value from one notification value from each service disable the same service by disabling notification within your notification callback function. for eg:-

```
static void SWNotifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify) 
{
  //store temperature value
  swchar=(char*)pData;
  //swbt=atoi(swchar);
  newsw=true;
  //Add Below line
  SWCharacteristics->getDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902))->writeValue((uint8_t*)notificationOff, 2, false);
}
```

2. You can just use one notification service that sends all three value at once
3. Add delay on your server code between each of the three service notify().

Ofcourse much can be done to tweak in your code but hopefully any of these should theoretically work.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it, later I tell you how work. Thanks